# CMD Copy last created items

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, backup

i have 6 folders with Database backup files named as *COMPANY*_Backup_*DATE*.rar . I want to copy every last file into one folder, compress and copy to my PC.

```
SET FECHA=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
rem Company1
XCOPY D:\BackupBBDD\COMPANY1\COMPANY1_backup_*.bak D:\BackupBBDD\CopiasBBDD\ /d /s
...
rem Company6
XCOPY D:\BackupBBDD\COMPANY6\COMPANY6_backup_*.bak D:\BackupBBDD\CopiasBBDD\ /d /s

rem rar and delete the folder
rar a -m5 -df -y Backup_RAR_%FECHA%.rar CopiasBBDD

rem copy to my pc
copy D:\BackupBBDD\Backup_RAR_%FECHA%.rar \\tsclient\D
```

Every time i execute this batch copies all files of every folder. Backup Files are created weekly, and the folder "CopiasBBDD" create ar begin of this script and deletes at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i founded a code who answers my question.

```
SET FECHA=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
SET DESTDIR=D:\BackupBBDD\CopiasBBDD\

@rem verify folders and copy last file.

@echo off
setlocal
set srcDir=D:\BackupBBDD\COMPANY1
set lastmod=
pushd "%srcDir%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a
if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
xcopy "%lastmod%" "%DESTDIR%"

...

set srcDir=D:\BackupBBDD\COMPANY6
set lastmod=
pushd "%srcDir%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a
if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
xcopy "%lastmod%" "%DESTDIR%"

rem RAR and copy

rar a -m5 -df -y Backup_RAR_%FECHA%.rar CopiasBBDD
xcopy D:\BackupBBDD\Backup_RAR_%FECHA%.rar \\tsclient\D
```